# Apply CSS to All Elements Within a Named div

Tags: html, css

I am using `:target`to hide divs from my page. which works great except the style is applied only to the first div on the page.

i am using this css

```
#mylist { display:block;}

#mylist:target { display:none;}
```

and i have a couple of elements with the same div

```
<a href="#mylist"> go </a>

<div id="mylist"> item 1 </div >
<div id="mylist"> item 2 </div >
<div id="mylist"> item 3 </div >
```

my problem is only the first Div gets hidden . how can i loop through all the elements ?

or is there an alternative way to achive this ？

Comment: IDs as a general rule of computing and life are used to uniquely identify something...

Comment: Also, it might just be the terminology you're using, but try not to think of CSS as 'looping', or you'll likely get *very* confused

Comment: use class in case you want to declare the same style for multiple elements

Comment: @bobbyJack that explains why i didn't get any luck with google

Comment: @Fuzzyma i am trying that at http://jsfiddle.net/bLhv19cr/ but couldn't figure it out

Comment: To use an elemet as anchor point you need to set an id. You cant use an id multiple times for a good reason because you can only jump to ONE element at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to hide elements using the target-property. This property is imo only usable on an anchorpoint. To define an element as anchorpoint you have to set an id.
To hide multiple elements at once you have to declare the parent as anchorpoint from which you then can manipulate the child-elements.

See a working example here:

```
<div id="mylist">
 <div> item 1 </div>
 <div> item 2 </div>
 <div> item 3 </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLhv19cr/1/

**Update**
Related to the comment below: http://jsfiddle.net/bLhv19cr/3/

Comment: well, that doe work but the divs aren't in that order , they are allover the place, there  are elements in between that doesn't need t be hidden .

Comment: Only the divs are hidden. Not any other elements. To be sure to hide only the right divs you can add a class which you can specify i the css instead of div. I will update the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

An ID is and must be unique.It applies only to one element.Use classes

Try this:

```
<div class="mylist"> item 1 </div >
<div class="mylist"> item 2 </div >
<div class="mylist"> item 3 </div >


.mylist { display:block;}

.mylist:target { display:none;}
```